# Trying to fix form resubmition with PRG (Getting error: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by)

Tags: plugins, posts, forms

I'm developing WordPress plugin which has POST form and I'm trying to fix the well-known bug - resubmission. I chose the method PRG (Post/Redirect/Get). I created separate file called `process.php` where I do some actions and redirect user back to the home page. However, when click on the button submit, I receive such warning:

> **Warning**: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at `/.../wp-content/themes/themeforest-12799586-gather-event-conference-wp-landing-page-theme/gather/header.php:12`) in `/.../wp-includes/pluggable.php` on *line 1228*

Ok, I opened Google and searched for this error. I found a lot of threads with only one solution - remove blank spaces before `<?php` and after `?>` php tags. I opened `header.php` file and didn't find any blank spaces. Here is my [header.php file](http://pastebin.com/Vi3rTH7H) and [process.php file](http://pastebin.com/DJaeJtc4).

Maybe someone knows where is the problem? And how to fix it? In first place, I would like to fix just resubmission bug. I've got this error only if I use such methods in my `process.php` file:

```
    $new_url = add_query_arg( 'success', 1, get_permalink() );
    wp_redirect( $new_url, 303 );
```

I appreciate your time and would be very thankful if you try to help me.

Comment: It would be easier to narrow down the problem if you provide your source code.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Just missed to add source code of my files. I edited my post. Here is header.php: http://pastebin.com/Vi3rTH7H and process.php file: http://pastebin.com/DJaeJtc4

Comment: Why are you using the get_header function? I think you shouldn't have any html code echoed in your process.php file. Also after wp_redirect you should exit; according to the documentation. Finally the email will never be sent due to redirection, right? Better use wp_safe_redirect for security reasons.

Comment: @Laxmana, Omg, I just missed to remove get_header function as well as paste redirection methods after all actions (I was just testing...). Now, I removed get_header function and changed wp_redirect to wp_safe_redirect and everything works perfectly! Many thanks!